# PHP turn data list into an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have following link which contains a lot of data (a lot). http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/all-items/all

The data is a list of ~50,000 sets of data, separated by commas.
Is there anyway I can convert this some 50,000 entries of data to an array?

Here is one entry of data for reference.

```
{
  "data_id":2,
  "name":"Assassin Pill",
  "rarity":1,
  "restriction_level":0,
  "img":"https:\/\/render.guildwars2.com\/file\/ED903431B97968C79AEC7FB21535FC015DBB0BBA\/60981.png",
  "type_id":3,
  "sub_type_id":1,
  "price_last_changed":"2014-05-10 20:00:13 UTC",
  "max_offer_unit_price":0,
  "min_sale_unit_price":0,
  "offer_availability":0,
  "sale_availability":0,
  "sale_price_change_last_hour":0,
  "offer_price_change_last_hour":0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is JSON data, Use

```
$yourarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/all-items/all'),true);
```

to convert them into an array.

Comment: And you would just use `echo $yourarray[0];` for first result, and etc?

Comment: If the array has user-defined keys, then you can't access that way.. Access them using the defined keys like this.. https://eval.in/149297